# display max on one columns with multiple columns in output

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I display maximum OrderId for a CustomerId with many columns?

I have a table with following columns:

```
CustomerId, OrderId, Status, OrderType, CustomerType
```

A customer with Same customer id could have many order ids(1,2,3..) I want to be able to display the max Order id with the rest of the customers in a sql view. how can I achieve this?

Sample Data:

```
CustomerId OrderId OrderType
145042       1        A
110204       1        C
145042       2        D
162438       1        B 
110204       2        B 
103603       1        C 
115559       1        D 
115559       2        A 
110204       3        A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a common table expression and [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
;With Ordered as (
    select *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID
                            ORDER BY OrderId desc) as rn
    from [Unnamed table from the question]
)
select * from Ordered where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table_name
where orderid in
(select max(orderid) from table_name group by customerid)
```

Comment: This query returns different number of rows than SELECT DISTINCT orderid FROM table_name. Shouldn't it return the same number of rows if CustomerId is not null for all records?

Comment: @user793468 - all of the answers so far will produce similar result sets. If those result sets aren't what you wanted, can you please edit your question and add some sample data (6-10 rows would probably be about right for this, with a couple of different customers and orders) and then what your expected results are for the query you're asking for.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Your query displays the right number of rows when i compare it to the SELECT DISTINCT orderid FROM table_name output.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.CustomerId = t.CustomerId and
                        t2.OrderId > t.OrderId
                 );
```

This is saying:  "get me all rows from `t` where there is no higher order id for the customer."

Comment: This query returns different number of rows than SELECT DISTINCT orderid FROM table_name. Shouldn't it return the same number of rows if CustomerId is not null for all records?

Comment: @user793468 . . . This would return a different number of rows if `orderid` is duplicated for some customer.

Comment: Yes, I just wrote a sql to find duplicates(OrderId and CustomerId) I found 7 duplicates!